# Automatically adding code-templates eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, code-templates

I have a Eclipse project.
I am searching for a way to generate code-templates that will appear automatically when I am adding a file to the project.
For example, I want to add a documentation code-template (eclipse's template is-

```
/**
 ** 
 ** @author:
 **/)
```

such that it will automatically appear in each java class file I add to the project, without making it manually.

Is there a good way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

You're able to change this behavior in

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code templates -> Comments -> Files
```

Comment: Hi, this one I know, just to be more clearer - I aim that the auto- documentation shown above will appear automatically every time *any* of the project's programmers (has the git repository) creates a new file, not just in my local eclipse

Comment: @shakedsapir In the mentioned preference page follow the link in the upper right corner _Configure Project Specific Settings..._ for that (or go directly to _Project > Properties: Java Code Style > Code Templates_).

Comment: @howlger Thank you very much! it is exactly what I was needed.
also thank you wiomoc for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Sharing @howlger answer:
In eclipse - *Window>Preferences>Configure Project Specific Settings>* choose project and then *ok* , then add any code-template you want.